# Получение данных input с HTML страницы с помощью JS (AJAX) и их передача в Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

В общем вопрос в следующем, я использую Flask, у меня есть обработчик первой страницы, к примеру

```
@application.route('/somepage1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def somepage1():
    return render_template('somepage1', data1=some1)
```

А также есть обработчик

```
@application.route('/somepage2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def somepage2():
        bla-bla
```

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы переменная data из первого захватывалась во второй обработчик, но простым `data2 = request.form['data1'];`я получить ее не могу, потому что вторая страница подгружается с помощью AJAX в первую и до тех пор пока она не подгрузится, переменной data1 из первой страницы для нее не существует, а мне нужно чтобы код работал на опережение, сначала data1 подгружалась в python обработчик, а только потом запускался AJAX скрипт используя полученную переменную. И вот я думаю, что JS в этом может мне помочь, но я почти ничего в нем не смыслю, как мне можно это реализовать?
Надеюсь понятно писал суть проблемы =)

Сам AJAX скрипт:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax_results",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#results_here').html(response)
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: передайте data в вашем ajax запросе

Comment: @5c0rp
Как я уже написал, я не силен в JS, не могли бы вы мне помочь, AJAX запрос выглядит так:
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_results",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                        $('#results_here').html(response)
                        console.log(response);
                        },
                       error: function(error) {
                       console.log(error);
                    }
                });

Добавил код ниже для корректного отображения

Comment: что собой представляет data?

Comment: @5c0rp
Это просто номер процесса (сессии, там ничего сложного): 
numb=123456, data=numb